# Remove value dropdown (multivalue) logic in JQuery

Tags: jquery, 2016

How to implement logic button "Remove" in JQuery to remove a value from dropdown (multivalue)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $("[id$='_SelectCandidate'] option[value='6']").remove();
    $("[id$='_SelectCandidate'] option[value='7']").remove();
    $("[id$='_SelectCandidate'] option[value='8']").remove();
    $("[id$='_SelectCandidate'] option[value='9']").remove();
    $("[id$='_SelectCandidate'] option[value='10']").remove();

    var $selOptions = "<OPTION title=Middle East value=6>Middle East</OPTION><OPTION title=North America value=7>North America</OPTION><OPTION title=Oceania value=8>Oceania</OPTION><OPTION title=South America value=9>South America</OPTION><OPTION title=The Caribbean value=10>The Caribbean</OPTION>";

    // this is the list of initial items (matching the ones above) that are used when the item is saved 

    var $resultSpOptions = "6|tMiddle East|7t|tNorth America|8t|tOceania|9t|tSouth America|t10|tThe Caribbean";

    $("[id$='_SelectResult']").append($selOptions);

    // append the new options to our hidden field (this sets the values into the list item when saving) 

    $("[id$='MultiLookup']").val($selOptions); 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a blog about this: https://derekgusoff.wordpress.com/2013/06/06/setting-multi-valued-lookups-in-forms-with-jquery/

Here's the function to remove the option. You might need to inspect to DOM to make sure the structure hasn't changed since 2013. Read the blog for more details:

```
//var selector = "[id$='MultiLookupPicker']"; //for 2010 or 2007
var selector = "[id$='MultiLookup']"; //for 2013


function removeChoice(text, columnName) {
    $("[title='" + columnName + " selected values'] option").each(function () {
        if ($(this).text() == text) {
            $(this).appendTo($("[title='" + columnName + " possible values']"));
            var multilookupPickerVal = $(selector).val();
            var valToRemove = $(this).val() + "|t" + $(this).text();
            var newValue = multilookupPickerVal.replace(valToRemove, "");

            $(selector).val(newValue);
        }
    });
}
```